# Choreographer Skipped 70 frames The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

For some reason in xamrain forms this is causing an instant crash of my app

```
private async void btnCopySessionToWeightLifting_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
        var item = dgSessions.SelectedItem as Session;
        if (item != null)
        {
           var action = await DisplayAlert(Constants.AppName, $"You 
            are about to copy all players in session 
            {item.SessionName} to weight lifting screen are you 
            sure?", "Yes", "No");
            if (action)
            {
                await             
         api.CopySessionsPlayersToWeightLiftingBySessionId(item.Id);
            await DisplayAlert(Constants.AppName, "Copy Complete", "", "No");
        }
        }
}
```

My Copy function

```
public async Task<HttpStatusCode> CopySessionsPlayersToWeightLiftingBySessionId(int Id)
{           
    EnsureHttpClientCreated();
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Id);
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
    var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    string URL = Constants.BaseUrl + Constants.ApiSegmant + Constants.CopySessionsPlayersToWeightLiftingBySessionId + $"?sessionID={Id}";
    httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(URL, httpContent);
      
    return httpResponse.StatusCode;

}
```

The only error I seem to get is this

**[Choreographer] Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**

I have tried simlar fixes on here but none of them have helped

Comment: how long does the `CopySessionsPlayersToWeightLiftingBySessionId `operation take?

Comment: You are getting this warning because you are blocking the UI thread making it impossible to update the UI. You should try to perform long running tasks to a separate thread.

Comment: How am I blocking it when my methods are async and await

Comment: Await doesn't always move the work to another thread. Could you try making an explicit threading. You can get the thread id using `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`

Answer (score 0):

I found that doing this seem to solve my main issue

```
await 
App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Constants.AppName,  
"Copy Complete", null, "Ok");
```

Notice the App.Current.MainPage. it seems to create a new thread.